# Are there any libraries that support MTOM encryption in Python

Tags: python, xml, soap, mtom

I am using Python Suds to connect to a webservice and I am wanting to use MTOM encrpytion to send an XML message. I have looked around the web and seen libraries for PHP etc. but not for Python. Can anyone recommend a good MTOM library to use preferably for use with SUDS.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you are talking about MTOM encryption or encoding.  If you are talking about encryption, then you are most likely looking for a WS Security solution. In this case [PyXMLSec](http://pyxmlsec.labs.libre-entreprise.org/) is a good option for XML Encryption and Digital Signatures.  However, I would caution against usage of XML Encryption as it is broken.  Instead, you could use [GPG encryption](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/10/python-gnupg-gpg-example/) or something similar.

If you are talking about MTOM encoding, then I don't believe there is a out of the box solution to do what you are asking, but it shouldn't be that hard.  MTOM use MIME attachments to send binary data.  You should be able to use Python's built in [email.mime package](http://docs.python.org/library/email.mime.html) to create MIME messages.

Comment: from what I can see PyXMLSec only supports actual XML encryption/decryption, but what about the attachments? Is there a library that can decrypt those as well?